# A problem on functoriality, identification of Cech and singular cohomology and cohomology of pairs.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

We have three smooth manifolds, $ A,M,X$ with smooth maps $A\overset{\iota}{\to}M\overset{r}{\to}X$,  $\iota$ is an inclusion (and in my head $X$ is $\mathbb{CP}^\infty$).

Suppose that, there is $[\omega]\in \check {H^*}(X)$ defining by restriction an element $[r^*\omega]\in \check {H^*}(M,A)$ (formally we should use covers see (*) below).
Everything is smooth so there are corresponding singular cohomology classes $\Phi([\omega])\in H^*(X)$ and $\Phi([r^*\omega])\in H^*(M,A)$.

[Here I am using that since $A,M,X$ are smooth, and the maps belong to the smooth category,  there exists $\Phi$ a natural equivalence of the functors $\check {H}$ and $H $ defining Cech and singular cohomology respectively.]

> 1)I would like to show that $\Phi([\omega]) = [\eta]\in H^*(X)$ and  $[r^*\eta] = \Phi([r^*\omega])\in H^*(M,A)$ for some $\eta \in C^*(X)$ a singular cocycle.

**Why (I think) is not that simple.**
The naive approach is to appeal to the functoriality of $\Phi$, however theres is not a map $(M,A)\to (X,\emptyset)$ to which we can apply $\Phi$.
What we do have is only a map $M\to X$, therefore for $r^*[\omega]\in \check{H^*}(M)$, $\Phi(r^*[\omega]) = r^*\Phi([\omega]) \in H^*(M)$. If we apply $\Phi$ to the LES for the pair $ (M,A)$ we obtain that $\Phi([r^*\omega])\in H^*(M,A) \mapsto r^*\Phi([\omega]) \in H^*(M)$ but this is a weaker conclusion.
Indeed it only implies that there is a representative $[\eta]= \Phi[\omega]$ such that $r^*\eta = \beta + d_M\alpha \in C^*(M)$ where $\beta\in C^*(M,A)$ therefore in general $r^*\eta\not\in C^*(M,A)$ because it vanishes only on cycles of $A$ not all chains of $A$. (Of course $[\beta] = \Phi([r^* \omega])\in H^*(M,A)$.)

**Edit after Thorgott's comment**
Since $\Phi([\omega])$ is in the image of $H^*(X,r(A))$ then it cohomologous to a cochain $\eta$ in the image of $C^*(X,r(A))$, therefore it vanishes on $r(A)$ so also $r^*\eta\in C^*(M,A)$.
This answers the initial  question (a part one technicality: why should an element in $C_*(A)\overset{r_*}{\to} C_*(r(A))$ be surjective if $r$ is not embedding).

However, I am not still satisfied, because  $H^*(X,A)\to H^*(X)$ is not injective in general, therefore there are more choices for the representative $\eta$, we know by using $\Phi$ that there will be one such that $[r^*\eta] = \Phi([r^*\omega])\in H^*(M,A)$ but it should be possible to define this element "canonically", I mean, in Cech cohomology it depends only on $[\omega]$ and the maps $r, \iota$, whilst in the singular case it seems that we have more choices and only using $\Phi$ we can find the "right " element.

> 2. How to characterize the element $\Phi([r^*\omega]) \in H^*(M,A)$ just in terms of $\Phi([\omega])\in H^*(X)$ and the maps $r,\iota$? There should be a "universal" property that does not appeal to $\Phi$.

(*)
To unravel the definition, this means that we can consider an open cover of $X$, $\mathfrak U$, belonging to a cofinal family of covers,
such that
cochain $\omega\in \check C^*(\mathfrak U)$, and  $\iota^*r^*\omega=0$, so it defines an element $r^*\omega\in \check C^*(r^*(\mathfrak U),r^*(\mathfrak U)|_A)$.

Comment: An element $[\omega]\in H^{\ast}(X)$ that defines an element in $H^{\ast}(M,A)$ by restriction is in the image of the restriction $H^{\ast}(X,A)\rightarrow H^{\ast}(X)$ (and vice versa), so what you really ought to be looking at are the maps induced by $(M,A)\subseteq(X,A)$ in relative cohomology and it seems like applying naturality of $\Phi$ to those resolves the issue.

Comment: @Thorgott thank you very much for your comment, there is still something that bothers me though, it doesn't fit a comment here so I updated the question.

Comment: Note that $H^{\ast}(X,A)\rightarrow H^{\ast}(X)$ possibly failing to be injective means that "restricting an element of $H^{\ast}(X)$ to $H^{\ast}(M,A)$" is, even when it is possible, not a well-defined operation. So, at the cohomology level, your question is not well-posed, and at the cochain level, Cech and singular theory are different. Rephrasing my previous comment, a choice of restriction as you wanna do it can be reduced to a choice of preimage along $H^{\ast}(X,A)\rightarrow H^{\ast}(X)$ and so studying the map induced by $(M,A)\subseteq(X,A)$ is the only sensible thing you can do.

Comment: @Thorgott What you are saying makes sense, thank you.